# How to set checkbox image while selecting table view section?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on a project and i stuck at a point. My project has a Table View with some data after clicking on the cell table view will expended into sections. Every thing is fine except one thing i.e i want to set a checkbox image (when the user clicked on a cell).
when i tap on the cell it gives the cell title text but i am not able to set the checkbox image (like **UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark**)on particular cell section.

I am posting the images and the codes below: !

[image: MyTableView it contains the Root Exercise Names]

**MyTableView it contains the Root Exercise Names**

[image: This is the Expended View and i want a checkbox(UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) at the right side of the cell.]

This is the Expended View and i want a checkbox(UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) at the right side of the cell.

[image: When i click on **tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** it works fine]

When i click on **tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** it works fine

//code

```
     -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        if ([indexPath isEqual:self.selectIndex]) {
            self.isOpen = NO;
            [self didSelectCellRowFirstDo:NO nextDo:NO];
            self.selectIndex = nil;

        }else
        {
            if (!self.selectIndex) {
                self.selectIndex = indexPath;
                [self didSelectCellRowFirstDo:YES nextDo:NO];

            }else
            {

                [self didSelectCellRowFirstDo:NO nextDo:YES];
            }
        }

    }else
    {
        NSDictionary *dic = [dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *list = [dic objectForKey:@"ExcerciseList"];            //from plist
        NSString *item = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
        UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
        {
            thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        }
        else
        {
            thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:item message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] ;
        [alert show];
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}


   #pragma mark- Table View DataSource and Delegates
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.isOpen&&self.selectIndex.section == indexPath.section&&indexPath.row!=0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";
        _cell = (Cell1*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!_cell) {
            _cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

            //[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        NSArray *list = [[dataList objectAtIndex:self.selectIndex.section] objectForKey:@"ExcerciseList"];
        _cell.titleLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];

        //[_cell changecheckboxWithUp:([self.selectIndex isEqual:indexPath]?YES:NO)];
        return _cell;
    }
    else
    {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"view_TableView_List";
        cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell=[[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        NSString *name = [[dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"Excercise_Name"];
        cell.Lbl_Excercise_Name.text = name;
        cell.Lbl_Excercise_Name.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Hustlers Rough Demo" size:40.0f];
        NSString *ImageName=[[dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"Excercise_Image"];
        [cell.imageView_Excercise_Image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:ImageName]];
        [cell changeArrowWithUp:([self.selectIndex isEqual:indexPath]?YES:NO)];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

**My Question is How to show Checkbox at the selected section?**

Sorry! if it is not formatted properly(New to stack)!
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to get it working. Here's what you have to change:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.isOpen&&self.selectIndex.section == indexPath.section&&indexPath.row!=0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";
        _cell = (Cell1*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!_cell) {
            _cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

            //[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        NSArray *list = [[dataList objectAtIndex:self.selectIndex.section] objectForKey:@"ExcerciseList"];
        _cell.titleLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
        _cell.accessoryView = nil;
        if ([self.selectedCells containsObject:indexPath])
        {
            _cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box@2x.png"]];
        }
        //[_cell changecheckboxWithUp:([self.selectIndex isEqual:indexPath]?YES:NO)];
        return _cell;
    }
    else
    {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"view_TableView_List";
        cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell=[[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        NSString *name = [[dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"Excercise_Name"];
        cell.Lbl_Excercise_Name.text = name;
        cell.Lbl_Excercise_Name.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Hustlers Rough Demo" size:40.0f];
        NSString *ImageName=[[dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"Excercise_Image"];
        [cell.imageView_Excercise_Image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:ImageName]];
        [cell changeArrowWithUp:([self.selectIndex isEqual:indexPath]?YES:NO)];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

**And**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        if ([indexPath isEqual:self.selectIndex]) {
            self.isOpen = NO;
            [self didSelectCellRowFirstDo:NO nextDo:NO];
            self.selectIndex = nil;

        }else
        {
            if (!self.selectIndex) {
                self.selectIndex = indexPath;
                [self didSelectCellRowFirstDo:YES nextDo:NO];

            }else
            {

                [self didSelectCellRowFirstDo:NO nextDo:YES];
            }
        }

    }else
    { 

        NSDictionary *dic = [dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *list = [dic objectForKey:@"ExcerciseList"];
        NSString *item = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
        UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!thisCell.accessoryView)
        {
            [self.selectedCells addObject:indexPath];
            thisCell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box@2x.png"]];

        }
        else
        {
            [self.selectedCells removeObject:indexPath];
            thisCell.accessoryView = nil;
        }

//        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:item message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] ;
//        [alert show];
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

If nothing else has changed in those methods, just copy-paste the code and it will work. I tested it before posting it. Let me know if you have more questions

**UPDATE**

Here is the explanation of what was going on. There were actually a couple of problems:

First, you were mixing `accessoryType` and `accessoryView`; this was causing an 
   incorrect execution of the `if-else` clause. Here is the old code

```
// here you are using accessoryType
if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
{
    // but here you're using accessoryView
    thisCell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box@2x.png"]];

}
else
{
    // here too...
    thisCell.accessoryView=nil;
    thisCell.accessoryView = nil;
}
```

Second, you were not saving the indexPaths of the selected elements. Here is the corrected code (note is the same `if-else` clause):

```
if (!thisCell.accessoryView)
{
    // you have to save the selected indexPaths
    [self.selectedCells addObject:indexPath];
    thisCell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box@2x.png"]];

}
else
{
    // if the cell was already selected, then remove the indexPath
    [self.selectedCells removeObject:indexPath];
    thisCell.accessoryView = nil;
}
```

Third, the following line inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath...` was messing up things because it was showing *another* checkmark, so I just removed it:

```
[_cell.checkUnCheck_ImageView setHidden:NO];
```

That was pretty much it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: its works! Thank you so much..! can u tell me the logic what u done in the code..!

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea of how to do this, however, you're setting the checkmark in the wrong place. You should use the method `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to store (remember) which cell was selected and NOT to set the accessory type.

If only one cell can be selected at a time you can declare a`NSIndexPath` property to remember the cell that was selected. However, if multiple cells can be selected at a time you can declare a `NSMutableArray` where you can store all the cells that have been selected.

Then you should use the method `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to set the checkmark to the cells that were selected.

Here is an example (I'm assuming multiple cells can be selected):

In your *.h file declare a `NSMutableArray` property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedCells;
```

In your *.m file, inside your init method initialize the property:

```
_selectedCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then, in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath...` method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if ([self.selectedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [self.selectedCells removeObject:indexPath]; // this line allows the checkmark to be shown/hidden if the user presses several times the same cell
    } else {
        [self.selectedCells addObject:indexPath]; // a cell was selected; remember it
    }

    ... // the rest of your code
}
```

Finally, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath...` method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ... // Create, initialize and customize your cell

    // if the cell you're being asked for is saved in the array it means it was selected
    if ([self.selectedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }
}
```

And that's it. Let me know if you have more questions

Hope it helps!

**UPDATE**

If all you want to do is to set a custom image as your checkmark just create the image and assign it to the accessory view while using the code that was already working for you, like so:

```
// Note that you should use 'accessoryView' and NOT 'accessoryType'
if (thisCell.accessoryView == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
{
    thisCell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"]];

}
else
{
    thisCell.accessoryView = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thankx for the answer but the problem is that this is an expendable table view cell and i need a custom Checkbox image at the place of check mark in the **Figure-3rd**. That is the section of the table view cell! Can you help me out pls..! For better understanding u can go with this link [My App link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tpigo43hlr709rg/ShareTheWeight_27th%20sept.mov).

Comment: After putting you code it shows different behaviour..! and when i print the indices for **selectedcell** it shows the checkbox when the root cell clicked..! really a tough task for me.!

Comment: Is the application in the video using the code you are showing here?

Comment: yes! the above code is for this app..! Any help will be very thankful..!

Comment: Alright, so you're already showing/hiding the checkmark, but what you want to do is put a custom image?

Comment: for your better understanding i am giving u the updated link please have a look..!**[updated link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rn18vqhc2s86pek/Demo.mov)** this is the another problem comes when i try to set my custom image.I am creating a cell through **cell** and the section cell by **_cell** i'm not able to determine the exact section index. hop u will understand my problem..!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38145/discussion-between-luiscien-and-amit-aman)